# sitecore MVC Web Form for Marketers - How to modify fields?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2, sitecore-mvc, web-forms-for-marketers

I've installed WFFM 2.4 on my Sitecore 7.2 MVC and its working correctly. Now I want to modify the way fields are being rendered so I can apply/use existing css. 
Has anyone come across this before? I'm changing the default.css to get some styling correct but there are some fields that I need to change the way they are being rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the folder yourhostname\Views\Form you have index.cshtml 
with the next content:

```
 @using Sitecore.Forms.Mvc
 @using Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Html
 @model Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.ViewModels.FormViewModel

@{
ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = Model.ClientId;

var main = string.Format("{0}main.js", Constants.ScriptsBaseUrl);
var requirejs = string.Format("{0}require-2.1.15.js", Constants.ScriptsBaseUrl);
var bootstrap = string.Format("{0}content/bootstrap.min.css", Constants.ScriptsBaseUrl);
var fieldsCss = string.Format("{0}content/Fields.css", Constants.ScriptsBaseUrl);
var jqueryui = string.Format("{0}content/themes/base/all.css", Constants.ScriptsBaseUrl);
}

@Html.RenderStyles(jqueryui, fieldsCss)

@if (Settings.EnableBootstrapCssRendering)
{
@Html.RenderStyles(bootstrap)
}

@Html.EditorFor(x => Model)

@Html.RenderScripts(requirejs)
@Html.RenderScripts(main)
```

You can change css and js files used. Above content is from a 8.1 solution but on 7.2 I guess is almost the same. On Views/Forms/EditorTemplates you have cshtml files for every type of fields.

[image]

Comment: Hi Sitecore Climber, I found that file and it allowed me to point to my custom css. However I need to modify the render itself. For example, I need to add a <div class="example"> around the fields. How can I achieve this? Am I missing something?

Comment: I reckon thats exactly what I was looking for! I imagine that if I need a custom field I'd have to add it there as well?

Comment: if you want a custom field you need to create your field here: /sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Field Types . I suggest you to check with dot peek how are made existing fields.